# Why selenium will auto close tabs in python when i open multiple tabs

Tags: python, selenium

python:3.9
selenium:4.1.0
Firefox:95.0.2

i want to open multiple tabs in firefox, then wait a while do somethings.
but after about 10 minutes tabs will disappear automatically,only one left,no exception no log.

```py
options = FirefoxOptions()
options.set_preference('dom.disable_open_during_load', False)
options.set_preference('dom.popup_maximum', -1)
options.set_preference('detach', True)
options.log.level = 'trace'
s = Service('./geckodriver')
browser = Firefox(options=options, service=s)

browser.get('https://www.google.com')
WebDriverWait(browser, 300).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'purchaseBtn')), message="crash")

js = 'window.open("https://www.google.com","_blank")'
for index in range(4):
    time.sleep(1)
    browser.execute_script(js)

while True:

    for hs in browser.window_handles:
        browser.switch_to.window(hs)

    logging.info('size:%s', len(browser.window_handles))
    time.sleep(5)

    if datetime.now().second >= 30:
        handles = browser.window_handles
        for handle in handles:
            browser.switch_to.window(handle)
            try:
                browser.find_element(By.ID, 'ID').click()
            except Exception as e:
                pass
        break
```

I searched google and the official website and found no results.
Maybe tabs are garbage collected?
---------------------------------------append---------------------------------------
append geckodriver log
1.last normal

```
1642818263474   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> GET /session/320b4aea-dc63-4baf-897c-078c829e4c9c/window/handles
1642818263474   Marionette  DEBUG   0 -> [0,735,"WebDriver:GetWindowHandles",{}]
  1642818263475 Marionette  DEBUG   0 <- [1,735,null,["b18d1ca3-54e8-4a7e-bae5-3278bb9b3d6b","1b7f8d40-b4a1-4b1a-9d21-001fb0beb68c","d81a70cc-a2f7-42aa-8538-eeb74f27c7c0","c7371d3e-6c9b-45bc-a55f-34d698c32d70"]]
1642818263475   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 200 OK {"value":["b18d1ca3-54e8-4a7e-bae5-3278bb9b3d6b","1b7f8d40-b4a1-4b1a-9d21-001fb0beb68c","d81a70cc-a2f7-42aa-8538-eeb74f27c7c0","c7371d3e-6c9b-45bc-a55f-34d698c32d70"]}
1642818263477   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> POST /session/320b4aea-dc63-4baf-897c-078c829e4c9c/window {"handle": "b18d1ca3-54e8-4a7e-bae5-3278bb9b3d6b"}
1642818263477   Marionette  DEBUG   0 -> [0,736,"WebDriver:SwitchToWindow",{"handle":"b18d1ca3-54e8-4a7e-bae5-3278bb9b3d6b","name":"b18d1ca3-54e8-4a7e-bae5-3278bb9b3d6b"}]
1642818263481   Marionette  TRACE   Received DOM event TabSelect for [object XULElement]
1642818263484   Marionette  DEBUG   0 <- [1,736,null,{"value":null}]
1642818263484   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 200 OK {"value":null}
1642818263486   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> POST /session/320b4aea-dc63-4baf-897c-078c829e4c9c/window {"handle": "1b7f8d40-b4a1-4b1a-9d21-001fb0beb68c"}
1642818263487   Marionette  DEBUG   0 -> [0,737,"WebDriver:SwitchToWindow",{"handle":"1b7f8d40-b4a1-4b1a-9d21-001fb0beb68c","name":"1b7f8d40-b4a1-4b1a-9d21-001fb0beb68c"}]
1642818263490   Marionette  TRACE   Received DOM event TabSelect for [object XULElement]
1642818263491   Marionette  DEBUG   0 <- [1,737,null,{"value":null}]
1642818263491   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 200 OK {"value":null}
1642818263493   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> POST /session/320b4aea-dc63-4baf-897c-078c829e4c9c/window {"handle": "d81a70cc-a2f7-42aa-8538-eeb74f27c7c0"}
1642818263493   Marionette  DEBUG   0 -> [0,738,"WebDriver:SwitchToWindow",{"handle":"d81a70cc-a2f7-42aa-8538-eeb74f27c7c0","name":"d81a70cc-a2f7-42aa-8538-eeb74f27c7c0"}]
1642818263496   Marionette  TRACE   Received DOM event TabSelect for [object XULElement]
1642818263499   Marionette  DEBUG   0 <- [1,738,null,{"value":null}]
1642818263499   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 200 OK {"value":null}
1642818263501   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> POST /session/320b4aea-dc63-4baf-897c-078c829e4c9c/window {"handle": "c7371d3e-6c9b-45bc-a55f-34d698c32d70"}
1642818263501   Marionette  DEBUG   0 -> [0,739,"WebDriver:SwitchToWindow",{"handle":"c7371d3e-6c9b-45bc-a55f-34d698c32d70","name":"c7371d3e-6c9b-45bc-a55f-34d698c32d70"}]
1642818263507   Marionette  TRACE   Received DOM event TabSelect for [object XULElement]
1642818263509   Marionette  DEBUG   0 <- [1,739,null,{"value":null}]
1642818263509   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 200 OK {"value":null}
1642818263511   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> GET /session/320b4aea-dc63-4baf-897c-078c829e4c9c/window/handles
1642818263511   Marionette  DEBUG   0 -> [0,740,"WebDriver:GetWindowHandles",{}]
1642818263511   Marionette  DEBUG   0 <- [1,740,null,["b18d1ca3-54e8-4a7e-bae5-3278bb9b3d6b","1b7f8d40-b4a1-4b1a-9d21-001fb0beb68c","d81a70cc-a2f7-42aa-8538-eeb74f27c7c0","c7371d3e-6c9b-45bc-a55f-34d698c32d70"]]
1642818263512   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 200 OK {"value":["b18d1ca3-54e8-4a7e-bae5-3278bb9b3d6b","1b7f8d40-b4a1-4b1a-9d21-001fb0beb68c","d81a70cc-a2f7-42aa-8538-eeb74f27c7c0","c7371d3e-6c9b-45bc-a55f-34d698c32d70"]}
2022-01-22 10:24:23
```

2.then one page missing

```
2022-01-22 10:24:28
1642818268520   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> GET /session/320b4aea-dc63-4baf-897c-078c829e4c9c/window/handles
1642818268521   Marionette  DEBUG   0 -> [0,741,"WebDriver:GetWindowHandles",{}]
  1642818268521 Marionette  DEBUG   0 <- [1,741,null,["b18d1ca3-54e8-4a7e-bae5-3278bb9b3d6b","d81a70cc-a2f7-42aa-8538-eeb74f27c7c0","c7371d3e-6c9b-45bc-a55f-34d698c32d70"]]
1642818268522   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 200 OK {"value":["b18d1ca3-54e8-4a7e-bae5-3278bb9b3d6b","d81a70cc-a2f7-42aa-8538-eeb74f27c7c0","c7371d3e-6c9b-45bc-a55f-34d698c32d70"]}
1642818268523   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> POST /session/320b4aea-dc63-4baf-897c-078c829e4c9c/window {"handle": "b18d1ca3-54e8-4a7e-bae5-3278bb9b3d6b"}
1642818268524   Marionette  DEBUG   0 -> [0,742,"WebDriver:SwitchToWindow",{"handle":"b18d1ca3-54e8-4a7e-bae5-3278bb9b3d6b","name":"b18d1ca3-54e8-4a7e-bae5-3278bb9b3d6b"}]
1642818268531   Marionette  TRACE   Received DOM event TabSelect for [object XULElement]
1642818268534   Marionette  DEBUG   0 <- [1,742,null,{"value":null}]
1642818268535   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 200 OK {"value":null}
1642818268537   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> POST /session/320b4aea-dc63-4baf-897c-078c829e4c9c/window {"handle": "d81a70cc-a2f7-42aa-8538-eeb74f27c7c0"}
1642818268537   Marionette  DEBUG   0 -> [0,743,"WebDriver:SwitchToWindow",{"handle":"d81a70cc-a2f7-42aa-8538-eeb74f27c7c0","name":"d81a70cc-a2f7-42aa-8538-eeb74f27c7c0"}]
1642818268542   Marionette  TRACE   Received DOM event TabSelect for [object XULElement]
1642818268543   Marionette  DEBUG   0 <- [1,743,null,{"value":null}]
1642818268543   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 200 OK {"value":null}
1642818268545   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> POST /session/320b4aea-dc63-4baf-897c-078c829e4c9c/window {"handle": "c7371d3e-6c9b-45bc-a55f-34d698c32d70"}
1642818268545   Marionette  DEBUG   0 -> [0,744,"WebDriver:SwitchToWindow",{"handle":"c7371d3e-6c9b-45bc-a55f-34d698c32d70","name":"c7371d3e-6c9b-45bc-a55f-34d698c32d70"}]
1642818268550   Marionette  TRACE   Received DOM event TabSelect for [object XULElement]
1642818268553   Marionette  DEBUG   0 <- [1,744,null,{"value":null}]
1642818268553   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 200 OK {"value":null}
1642818268554   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> GET /session/320b4aea-dc63-4baf-897c-078c829e4c9c/window/handles
1642818268555   Marionette  DEBUG   0 -> [0,745,"WebDriver:GetWindowHandles",{}]
1642818268555   Marionette  DEBUG   0 <- [1,745,null,["b18d1ca3-54e8-4a7e-bae5-3278bb9b3d6b","d81a70cc-a2f7-42aa-8538-eeb74f27c7c0","c7371d3e-6c9b-45bc-a55f-34d698c32d70"]]
1642818268555   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 200 OK {"value":["b18d1ca3-54e8-4a7e-bae5-3278bb9b3d6b","d81a70cc-a2f7-42aa-8538-eeb74f27c7c0","c7371d3e-6c9b-45bc-a55f-34d698c32d70"]}
```

---------------------------------------append---------------------------------------
It may be because of the problem caused by 'WebDriverWait',but don't know why.

Comment: You might add firefox option to enable geckodriver verbose logging `{"moz:firefoxOptions": {"log": {"level": "trace"}}}`, maybe some errors will be listed in the logs. Also try to find the exact moment when it's happened. I understand, this is like a hunting, but looks like you have to do some research to know what happened.. This is uncommon behaviour, it can be a geckodriver bug.

Comment: Try without any preferences set first... just to see.  It seems like the one preference you are setting shouldn't allow any new tabs... not sure why it's still creating them.  Also be aware that firefox has different window handles for local and remote.  A blank tab has a local... that will switch to a remote handle once the URL is loaded.  Right now there may not be enough time for the handles to update.  (if so, add a sleep...)  You may also want to use JS to open the new tab, but Selenium to navigate (that would ensure a proper wait)  So open new>switch to that handle>navigate>open new>...

Comment: @MaxDaroshchanka  thanks for the reply.I try,
Sadly, still no exception logs

Comment: @pcalkins "dom.disable_open_during_load" in order to prevent firefox from blocking when creating a new tab.  There are no options at first,I've tried looping through tabs before or looping through creating closing tabs,to no avail~~.

Comment: I was referring to dom.popup_maximum at -1